# Rearranging axes in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an ndarray such as

```
>>> arr = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30, 40)
>>> arr.shape
(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

whose axes I would like to swap around into some arbitrary order such as

```
>>> rearranged_arr = np.swapaxes(np.swapaxes(arr, 1,3), 0,1)
>>> rearranged_arr.shape
(40, 10, 30, 20)
```

Is there a function which achieves this without having to chain together a bunch of `np.swapaxes`?

Comment: `np.transpose` can most move multiple axes at a time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are two options: [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) and [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

- ### `np.moveaxis(a, sources, destinations)` [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html)

  This function can be used to rearrange ***specific*** dimensions of an 
  array. For example, to move the 4th dimension to be the 1st and the 2nd dimension to be the last:

  ```py
  >>> rearranged_arr = np.moveaxis(arr, [3, 1], [0, 3])
  >>> rearranged_arr.shape
  (40, 10, 30, 20)
  ```

  This can be particularly useful if you have many dimensions and only want to rearrange a small number of them. e.g.

  ```py
  >>> another_arr = np.random.rand(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
  >>> np.moveaxis(another_arr, [8, 9], [0, 1]).shape
  (8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
  ```
- ### `np.transpose(a, axes=None)` [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

  This function can be used to rearrange ***all*** dimensions of an array at once. For example, to solve your particular case:

  ```py
  >>> rearranged_arr = np.transpose(arr, axes=[3, 0, 2, 1])
  >>> rearranged_arr.shape
  (40, 10, 30, 20)
  ```

  or equivalently

  ```py
  >>> rearranged_arr = arr.transpose(3, 0, 2, 1)
  >>> rearranged_arr.shape
  (40, 10, 30, 20)
  ```

Comment: `np.moveaxis` is very useful to manipulate on tensor objects. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, I have done my best to improve the answer beyond what would turn up in a trivial google search.

Comment: Apparently, no shuffling occurs on```np.moveaxis```. I did not test transpose.

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> arr = np.random.rand(10, 20, 30, 40)                                                               
>>> arr.transpose(3,0,2,1).shape                                                                       
(40, 10, 30, 20)
```